# Simple dataset query fails

Tags: dataset

This is really weird.

I can get the first row and a specific column from my Dataset, but when I try to get them both, I receive a cryptic error.

[image]

What in the world could it be talking about. myData is the result of a query on a huge proprietary dataset that I really can't upload here. Obviously something simple is broken, but what is it? But more importantly, how do I avoid unexpected breakage like this in the future. Is there a RestoreSanityToDataset[] function?

Oddly, if I add curly braces around the column name, it works fine

[image]

Perhaps the FullForm of myData holds a clue. Maybe a Dataset master could look at this and see right off.

```
    FullForm[Dataset[{Association["Charge" -> 2], 
   Association["Charge" -> 1]}, TypeSystem`AnyType, 
     Association[
   "Origin" -> 
    HoldComplete[
     Query[1 ;; 2, {"Charge"}][
      Dataset`DatasetHandle[183820416144600]]], 
       "ID" -> 46304153328976]]]
```

Comment: What it is talking about is that you have no key "a"; Only the key "Charge".

Comment: Just a typo in my post. I'll fix it shortly.

Comment: Interestingly, the same error is returned whether I type "Charge" or I type "Foo" or anything else. It's saying that a string isn't _applicable_ as a part selection. It's not even looking at the actual string.

Comment: It is normal [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/22lrS.png)

Comment: Yes, @yode, that obviously works. But I have something with the same Normal as what you typed, that came as a result of a query. That simple result that looks entirely the same does _not_ work with that simple query. That's why I included the FullForm. Clearly I'm insane or the type system in Datasets is fubar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but an extended comment that includes a work-around.

When I copy the argument of `FullForm` as `InputForm` and paste it into a input cell I see

[image: dataset]

That's a dataset expression of a form I've never seen before and one that the Mathematica's code editor doesn't recognize either. You may be making a simple query, but you are querying something that does not appear to be a simple dataset. I'm not surprised that it behaves strangely.

It occurred to me that it might behave better if it were renormalized.

```
newds = Dataset[ds // Normal]
```

[image: newds]

Now

```
newds[1 ;; 2, "Charge"]
```

gives

[image: result]

as expected.

Comment: Define "simple dataset". I'm querying something that is a list of associations. All associations in the list have exactly the same keys. The value associated with each key has exactly the same structure, typically just one number, but sometimes a list of numbers. I'm really not doing anything fancy -- I thought. It's so _frustrating_ when you invest many days to learn a new topic (Datasets), build something from it, and then encounter erratic behavior nobody understands.

Comment: Indeed, renormalizing fixes it. But that's the crux of the question. Is it expected practice to need to renormalize after every query? If so, why isn't that the _default_ format of a query result? Perhaps Dataset[#//Normal] processing should be the default and there should be an option _Abnormal_ to give you the abnormal behavior should you actually want it.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich. I did not mean 'simple' as technical term; the usual dictionary definition will do. Or the renormalized form my be considered to define simple in this case. Datasets are a work in progress. They behave a lot better in V11.1.1 than they did in V10.0. I can't say more because the dataset you use in your example was derived by querying another more complicated dataset and you give no information about that process.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich. Unfortunately, I have found renormalization is often necessary, but less so in V11.1.1 than in previous versions. It is something any user of datasets should keep in mind when weirdness happens.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to understand these may not be ready for prime time. But regarding the "you give no information about the bigger dataset" thing, riddle me this: why should it matter? Seriously. Why, ever, in any case, should I need to add curly braces to the column name, making it a list, _only_ when more than one row is selected? Sounds to me like a bug, plain and simple.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich. That is was derived from another dataset does matter. Maybe it shouldn't. Maybe it is a bug (there are plenty of them). But your derived dataset does not have the normal form, and that is something you must deal with.

Comment: On slide two of the presentation on Datasets given at the Wolfram Tech Conference 2014 is the claim that Datasets are intended to solve the problem: "if something goes wrong it can be hard to understand why". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ks1iJSXy1CQ

Comment: @ChrisNadovich. Well, that's a nice sentiment and great goal the development team to have :-P Let us pray that we will live to see its achievement.